# Google map camera position on multiple markers

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google map API 2 and showing multiple markers on it.  My problem it that I want my camera to be positioned on all my markers.
  I have done it for single marker as

```
 myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MyLocation, 22));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have Used Below Way to see all markers in view. It will Bound your Mapview including all the Lat-Long Location you have in your arraylist.

```
 // Pan to see all markers in view.
 // Cannot zoom to bounds until the map has a size.
    final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getView();
    if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < YOUR_ARRAYLIST.size(); i++) {           
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(i).getPos().getLat(), YOUR_ARRAYLIST.get(i).getPos().getLon());
            bld.include(ll);            
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = bld.build();          
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 70));
                mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            }
        });
    }
```

Hope it Will Help.

Comment: Working like charm. Thanks

Comment: removeGlobalOnLayoutListener is deprecated, use removeOnGlobalLayoutListener instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to move camera incase of multiple markers

```
//Create your LatLngBounds builder
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

// iterate through all your markers
markersList.forEach { marker ->
    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
}

// move camera to the bounds with padding
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 100));
```