# Android Google Maps v2 : Camera out of bound on initial loading. On resuming app, camera in focus

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I've been trying to build an app which consume json data containing Latitude and Longitude, create multiple markers and pin them to a map.

All is going well except for this weird behavior - On initial loading, the map camera is out of bound.

[image: On Intial loading]

If the app goes to background,and on resuming it, the camera focus is now correct.

[image: On Resuming the app]

Here's the code I'm using for creating the marker as well as defining the bounds.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded(ArrayList<MarkerObject> mapMarkers2) {

    if(mMap == null) {

        mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
        if(mMap != null) {

            /*setUpMap(mapMarkers);
            Log.i(TAG,"SetUpMap is called");*/

            for(int i=0; i<mapMarkers2.size(); i++) {

                customMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(mapMarkers.get(i).getLatitude(), mapMarkers.get(i).getLongitude()))
                .title(mapMarkers.get(i).getName())
                .snippet(mapMarkers.get(i).getContact()));

            }

            //Required for focusing the camera

            final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getView();
            if(mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {

                mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {

                        /*LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                                                              .include(markerLatLng).build();*/

                        LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                        for(int i=0; i<mapMarkers.size(); i++) {

                            LatLng ll = new LatLng(mapMarkers.get(i).getLatitude(), mapMarkers.get(i).getLongitude());

                            bld.include(ll);
                        }

                        LatLngBounds bounds = bld.build();

                        /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }else {

                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                        */
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,10));
                        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
                        mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                        Log.i(TAG,"Camera position: "+ mMap.getCameraPosition());

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving animateCamera and Cameraupdatefactory inside try Catch solved the issue. Here's the code

```
          try{
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(llb,15));

            }catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getView();
                Log.i(TAG,"MapView is obtained ");

                if(mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {

                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                                    } else {
                                        mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                        .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                                    }

                                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(llb,1));
                                }
                    });

                };

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(llb,15));

           };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `moveCamera` in the onMapLoaded listener:

```
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        // moveCamera here
    }
});
```

Comment: Same result !!. I've called onMapLoaded listener inside `public void onGlobalLayout()`. Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Global Tree observer, add your markers, create a LatLng[] with all of your points and use code below for zooming to all points on your map. I've added a little bonus for getting a nice padding. (you can also call this method onResume if you like)

```
        public void zoomToPoints(LatLng... geoPoint){
        LatLngBounds.Builder b = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (LatLng m : geoPoint)
        {
            if (m != null)
                b.include(m);
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = b.build();
        int padding = (int) (Math.min(DEVICE_WIDTH, DEVICE_HEIGHT) * 0.1);
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        mMap.animateCamera(cu);
}
```

I also suggest to add a handler to delay the map init to avoid main thread staggering especially if you're using lots of pins. Build your map in OnCreate and delay the pins drawing.

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            drawPinsAndZoom();
         }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540220/google-map-camera-position-on-multiple-markers . It works for others, but not in my code. Any thoughts on what's not working