# How to populate an ArrayList of Markers with an ArrayList of LatLang

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have this two arrays

```
  private LinkedList<LatLng> linkedLatLang = new LinkedList<>();
    private ArrayList<Marker> mMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
```

My first array contains all the latitudes and longitudes, now, I need to populate the Marker array with all those LatLangs and I cant figure it out how to do it

this is what I need to do

```
mMarkers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(here_i_need_to_get_all_latlangs));
```

Comment: There's an example of how to create a `Marker` in the documentation for that class: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#example. You need to call `addMarker()` on your `GoogleMap`, passing your `MarkerOptions` object. You would then `add()` that to your `List`.

Comment: Why don't you use java 1.8 streams like -> `List<Marker> markers = linkedLatLang.stream().map(next -> createMarkerFromLatLng(next)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment given by @Mike M., you need a `GoogleMap` instance. With a given instance of `GoogleMap`, `map`, you can:

```
GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
linkedLatLang.forEach(e -> mMarkers.add(map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(e))));`
```

Comment: this wont work since .position(e) is not the type of LatLang, instead you are doing like linkedList.size and passing i on it, instead it should be linkedlist.get(i)

Comment: `position(e)` returns `MarkerOptions`, which is what the `map.addMarker` needs, it is better you give more code snippet, for instance including the `GoogleMap` instance

Answer (score 0):

- First, you have `LinkedList` not `ArrayList`.
- Second, I don't think, it's a good idea to keep all markers in memory. They are heavier than LatLng.
- Third, if you want to populate them, you can just use for
  loop. But instead of that, I would use `mMap.addMarker` to let google's API clear memory, when the user doesn't on the current part of the map right now.

Comment: the idea is to set the bounds of the camera with the latlangs

Comment: How about this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540220/google-map-camera-position-on-multiple-markers